# Dynamic Create column in sql server with datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `TAB_A`

```
COL_NAME DATATYPE MAX_LENGTH
A        VARCHAR   255
B        INT        4
C        FLOAT      8
```

I want to create A,B,C as column in `TAB_B` with `DATATYPE` and `MAX_LENGTH`.

The `TAB_B` columns look like this: Before

```
X Y Z
```

I want the `TAB_B` look like this: After

```
X Y Z A B C
```

with datatype.

How can I write dynamic SQL so my A,B,C,... columns will get created in existing table.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below,

I have created sample table like your example:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab_A
(
    COL_NAME       CHAR(1),
    DATATYPE       VARCHAR(100),
    MAX_LENGTH     INT
)

insert into Tab_A values('A',        'VARCHAR',   255)
insert into Tab_A values('B',        'INT' ,       4)
insert into Tab_A values('C',        'FLOAT'  ,    8)
```

Now I have created other table Tab_B,

```
CREATE TABLE Tab_B
(
    X       CHAR(1),
    Y       VARCHAR(100),
    Z     INT
)

SELECT * from Tab_B
```

Now, Finally I'm using dynamic query,

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') 
       + QUOTENAME(COL_NAME) + ' ' + DATATYPE + CASE WHEN DATATYPE = 'INT' THEN '' ELSE '(' + CAST(MAX_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) +')' END
FROM   (
           SELECT DISTINCT *
           FROM   Tab_A
       ) AS Courses

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE Tab_B ADD ' + @ColumnName + ''
EXEC (@SQL)
SELECT * FROM   Tab_B
```

Comment: for int we got error...like ...Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

Comment: There is no INT(4) data type in SQL server. So please check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, but this is temp because if datatype is date or bigint then the same prob....where can i get list of fixed length datatype in sql server. so i can make this is my answer

Comment: can you please check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271(v=sql.80).aspx - for type int you should make `tinyint,smallint,int,bigint,real`

Comment: also try this `SELECT * FROM sys.types` to get all data types

Comment: anytime@Jack ----- great day ahead. :)

Answer (score 1):

This statement will provide the desired query:

```
DECLARE @TAB_A SYSNAME = 'dbo.Tab_A'
, @TAB_B SYSNAME = 'dbo.Tab_B'

DECLARE @dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @dynsql = COALESCE(@dynsql,'') + qry
FROM (
SELECT
'ALTER TABLE ' + @TAB_B + ' ADD COLUMN '
+ COLUMN_NAME
+ ' ' + DATA_TYPE
+ CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN ' ' WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN '(MAX) ' ELSE '(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) + ') ' END
+ CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' END
+ CASE WHEN COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' DEFAULT ' + COLUMN_DEFAULT END
+ '; ' AS qry
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TAB_A,1)
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = COALESCE(PARSENAME(@TAB_A,2),'dbo')
) r

SELECT @dynsql
```

Now you can also replace the

```
SELECT @dynsql
```

with

```
EXEC(@dynsql)
```

but be aware that your table A will be altered when executing.

Comment: It alter my existing column only, and not adding new one